# Loop is not correctly changing element positions

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, automation, webdriver-io

I want to automate a test case, where I need to sort items in descending order by their numeric values. For sorting user story list items might change. In start they look from the beginning it looks at this [values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEhWn.png). I used hash for this

```
 var values = $$('div.vertical-list-container div.list-group-item');
 var numberHash = { 'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4, 'Five': 5, 'Six': 6, 'Seven': 7, 'Eight': 8, 'Nine': 9, 'Ten': 10 };
```

After I created the loop where I collected all these elements.

```
 for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
            {
                numberArray.push(numberHash[values[i].getText()])
            }
```

So now loops looks this [1,2,3,4,5,6]
After that, I used bubble sort to make descending order

```
 function bubble_Sort(a)
            {
            var swapp;
            var n = a.length-1;
            var x=a;
            do {
                swapp = false;
                for (var i=0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (x[i] < x[i+1])
                    {
                       var temp = x[i];
                       x[i] = x[i+1];
                       x[i+1] = temp;
                       swapp = true;
                    }
                }
                n--;
            } while (swapp);
         return x; 
        }
            bubble_Sort(numberArray);
```

And in the last loop, I have a problem.

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
                var elem = values[i];
                var elemNumber = numberHash[values[i].getText()];
                var index = numberArray.findIndex((element) => element == elemNumber);
                var target = values[index];
                elem.dragAndDrop(target);
              }
```

All values changed positions except 2.  I know why it is( because after .dragAndDrop function value 1 goes below 6, and now value 2 is in zero position, but loop start check next position.
So now I have ordered values in this order => [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bz4v.png)[6,2,5,4,3,1] instead of [6,5,4,3,2,1]. Can someone know how to fix it? Where is the problem in the loop? I really need to this :(

Comment: Why `bubble_Sort()` when there's `Array.prototype.sort()`? (and how is this relevant for this question?)

Comment: I think it will help explain the problem much more clearly, and I didn't know about `Array.prototype.sort()` function! Thank you about this, but my issue still is not resolved :(

Comment: you should use .sort().reverse() as I explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by myself

```
var moved = true
    
    while(moved){

            values = $$('div.vertical-list-container div.list-group-item');
            moved = false
            for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            var elem = values[i];
            var elemNumber = numberHash[values[i].getText()];
            var index = numberArray.findIndex((element) => element == elemNumber);
            if(i === index){continue}
            var target = values[index];
            elem.dragAndDrop(target);
            moved = true;                   
        }
```

Now loop is changing values correctly